# Deleted Migration folder (Django 1.8) by accident what are my options?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have accidently deleted one of migrations folders and and have no backup for it.

What are my options?

DB is postgres. Right now everything is OK.(I have moved instead  migration folder I have on my DEV server with SQL lite)  So I am just getting red message on server that not all migrations have been applied.

But next time if i run migration i will be in trouble.

What is my way out?

Comment: Depends - do you have anything that can undelete? Ultimately it'll be a learning experience: always have backups of important stuff.

Comment: nope i did it via ftp. on my digital ocean account. I have no clue about how it works on Unix. I will check if there any recycle bin option there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are mainly for backward compatibility, and tracking/versioning of the changes to models/database. If you do not really care about historical changes, etc.. then you can just delete the migrations directory and do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

This creates the initial migrations (like starting from a clean slate) - and moving forward you can track the historical migrations moving forward. More on [this can be read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations)

Now, when you run the migrations, you can do

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> --fake-initial
```

to fake the [initial migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#initial-migrations).

Now might be a good time to have a version control on your application

Answer (score 1):

### Use version control.

You are not the first developer to delete important files, but often recovery takes less than a second - thanks to version control systems (also called revision control systems). Please stop everything else and install and use one of Git, Mercury or Subversion.

### Don't use FTP

It's totally. I mean totally insecure. Always use SFTP

### Don't use sqlite3 for local with other db for production

sqlite doesn't enforce strict type checking. Postgresql on the other hand is very particular about it. Additionally sqlite only has a subset of the functionality that's found on postgresql. Last but not least different RDBMS have different intricacies. If you use one locally and another in production, there is always a chance that your code will break when you deploy to live

### Managing without the migration files

This is not a big loss as long as your database is in sync with your models.

If you database is not in sync with your models, you can use

```
./manage.py inspectdb
```

to recreate local models that represent the actual structure in the db. Then you do makemigrations and migrate (as explained by karthik) on the generated models.

Then replace that with your live models and do the step again.